# How to Use shell variable in the If condition of Awk(inside single quotes)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I need to write the this statement:

`cat filename | awk -F '|' '($4 ~ /"$Var_PRJ"/) && ($7 == "Y")'`.

However, `$Var_PRJ` is not getting expanded (may be because `awk` uses single quotes). How can I get this implemented with actual value of `Var_PRJ`?

Note: `cat filename | awk -F '|' '($4 ~ /1234/) && ($7 == "Y")'` is working fine.

Comment: Did you attempt to search for a solution?

Comment: you can use -v switch 
example
`$ x=1`
`$ awk -v var=$x 'BEGIN{print var}'`
1

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick

```
awk -F '|' '($4 ~ /'"$Var_PRJ"'/) && ($7 == "Y")' filename
```

Notice double quotes before and after BASH variable

Comment: Downvoter please explain reason for downvoting.

Comment: I just downvoted because this would make the shell variable expand to become part of the actual awk script and so lead to cryptic errors (and probably security vulnerabilities). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script.